# Execute step only if previous step timed out

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a setup where an automated test suite is executed. Based on the result we send different notifications. However, when the test step times out no notification is sent atm. Is there a way to know if a specific github actions step has timed out? Or an env var counting the the time that has passed since the job started?

I assume I could assign variables with the start and end time but hope there is an easier way.

Kind regards

Comment: According to [the status check functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions) there is no way to identify if a step timed out or not, just if it failed, succeeded or were canceled. Did you try adding a `continue-on-error: true` field to the next step to check if it was executed if the previous step timeout?

Comment: Ok good to know, I am solving this by setting an envvar at the start of the execution step then adding a step that calculates if the diff is longer than the timeout we set.